# Confused about javascript object keys

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, octal

If I define a new Object in javascript, with `var myobject = {}` I will have an empty object, as expected. However, I fail to understand the logic behind this. Note that it all works, but I don't get it, more a tease than anything else:

```
var myobject = {};                 // Object{}
    myobject[001] = "001";         // Object {1: "001"}, So 001 turns to 1
    myobject[0099999] = "0099999"; // Object {1: "001", 99999: "0099999"}
    //Last line only makes sense after this one (shortened version)▼
    myobject[0023122] = "0023122"  // Object {... 9810: "0023122" ...}
```

I know I can't access those properties with `myobject.0023122` since they start with a digit, but I can't by doing this `myobject['0023122']` either so I'm assuming that the number 0023122 is transformed to the property with a key `9810` since I **can** do `myobject['9810']` and get the result.

What's fascinating about this is that I can do `myobject[99999]` and `myobject['99999']` so javascript didn't need to reject my key although I lose my leading zeros. I'm not talking about what's wrong and right to do, just what is the reason for the number `0023122` to be converted to `9810` while <strike>even `0023123` converts gracefully to 23123 just as</strike> `0099999` converts to `99999`

- I assumed it was too big of a number, that's why I tried with one even bigger.
- If you remove the leading zeros, the key becomes "23123"

Comment: it's converted before it ever becomes a key. quote it to preserve zeros. all object keys are strings anyway, so just start with a strign and avoid the issue you demonstrate.

Comment: Solution is to "use strict" .

Comment: @elclanrs: how does use strict affect extra leading zeros on Numbers? the zeros will still be thrown away, they just won't leave an octal behind...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript supports octal numbers:

> Positive octal numbers must begin with 0 (zero) followed by octal digit(s).

0023122 (in octal) is 9810 (in decimal)

So any number that has all digits less than 8, but starts with a 0, will be converted to octal.

If it has an 8 or 9, it will get truncated if it starts with a 0.

091 -> 91

but

071 -> 57

Of course, if you use string keys, nothing to worry about:

```
 myobject["001111"] = "001111"
 myobject[001111] = 585
```

Comment: Sweet, I knew it had an explanation. I had an issue with this and this explains it. 0999 doesn't compute as octal, 0123 or whatever does. End of mystery :)

Answer (score 1):

If a number in JS starts with a zero, it's assumed to be octal, which is why the key is converted. `myobject[0099999]` might actually cause an error as it isn't a valid octal number because it contains 9s (but this may vary depending on browser/interpreter)

Answer (score 1):

In the code `myobject[0023122] = "0023122";` the value used as an index for object is evaluated as a integer primitive.

The prefix of 0 causes it to be interpreted as an OctalIntegerLiteral, meaning that 0023122 is evaluated as octal. Had it been 23122 it would be evaluated as an IntegerLiteral. 0x23122 would cause it to be evaluated as a HexIntegerLiteral.

See more here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3